# Javascript set cookie to remember latest option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set cookie here, to remember the  latest option selected?
I don't have any cookie code, and I don't know much about `javascript`, I just started learning and I hope someone can help me to show me that code. Thanks

This is my code

```
       $("#AL-IMG").on('click', function() {
   $("#div-AL-IMG").css({ 'display': "block" });

    $("#div-EN-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
      $("#div-ES-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
        $("#div-FR-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
          $("#div-IT-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
});

   $("#EN-IMG").on('click', function() {
   $("#div-EN-IMG").css({ 'display': "block" });

    $("#div-AL-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
      $("#div-ES-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
        $("#div-FR-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
          $("#div-IT-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
});

   $("#FR-IMG").on('click', function() {
   $("#div-FR-IMG").css({ 'display': "block" });

    $("#div-EN-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
      $("#div-ES-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
        $("#div-AL-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
          $("#div-IT-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
});

   $("#ES-IMG").on('click', function() {
   $("#div-ES-IMG").css({ 'display': "block" });

    $("#div-AL-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
      $("#div-EN-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
        $("#div-FR-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
          $("#div-IT-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
});

   $("#IT-IMG").on('click', function() {
   $("#div-IT-IMG").css({ 'display': "block" });

    $("#div-EN-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
      $("#div-ES-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
        $("#div-AL-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
          $("#div-FR-IMG").css({ 'display': "none" });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit the question to include all relevant information, which in cases such as this also includes the necessary HTML in order to understand the Javascript you have provided.

To set a cookie, please checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 0):

your question is not cleared, but as per the title

> Javascript set cookie to remember latest option selected

the following might be helpful

you can set cookie on dropdownchange event

```
$('#dropdown').change(function()) {
   $.cookie("mydropdown", $('#dropdown').val()); //set cookie
   $.cookie("mydropdown", $('#dropdown', { expires : 10 }); //set cookie with expiration
}
```

and to read you cookie

```
var cookieDropdown = $.cookie("mydropdown");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the cookie you can store that value in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

For setting value 
`localStorage.setItem("latestSelection", "Option1");`

For retrieving value
`var latestSelection = localStorage.getItem("latestSelection");`